# In for loop of JavaScript, when we iterate, how come it gives result from 0 to 9 in given code when x is a string. It should concat rather

Tags: javascript, string, for-loop

```
let x = ""; //Here we have defined x as a string*
    
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    x += i + "<br>"; // and here we are adding string to a number so, the result should be concatenation.
}

document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = x; //
```

But when we get result, we get numbers from 0 - 9. How Come?

Comment: what is the html? what are you expecting exactly?

Comment: What do you expect to happen with numbers that are converted into strings? o.O

Comment: Please add more details. What is the expected result? What is the actual result?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers **what the expected behavior should be**. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. **Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question**."_

Answer (score 2):

Because you started with i being 0, and you iterate so long as i is less than 10. So it starts at 0, and once i reaches 10 it exits the loop without executing the code in your loop for the value 10.

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with the question - it seems to be about concatenation, but not about amount of  iterations

Comment: This precisely answers the question @nicael: _"But when we get result, we get numbers from 0 - 9. How Come?"_.

Comment: Well anyway, the question is now closed as unclear, @Andy